# How can I grab a user's Discord banner at full resolution?

Tags: javascript, image, discord, banner

I have created a feature where a user can input information about themself and an embed is created. I want to add the user's banner to the embed, however, when I run the code below I just get a smaller version of it.

(this is just a bit of the code isolated, it's the same result though)

```
async run(interaction) {
    await interaction.deferReply();

    await interaction.user.fetch();
    interaction.editReply({ content: interaction.user.bannerURL({ dynamic: true }) });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was being stupid, there is a [size option](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/typedef/StaticImageURLOptions).

For anyone else that needs help with this:

```
async run(interaction) {
    await interaction.deferReply();

    await interaction.user.fetch();
    interaction.editReply({ content: interaction.user.bannerURL({ dynamic : true , size : 2048 }) });
}
```